# Is it ok to use material ui and tailwind css both with react js for building web-app?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, tailwind-css

I am going to build an app in react and was thinking to use material-ui and tailwind css.So my question is does using both of them in same project make any conflict. I need strong suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

you can use that but you have everything in materialui or in tailwind so for my case I will use MaterialUI for whole app and styled components

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you combine both with [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro) its great combindation of tailwind and styled-components. And i think its the best way how to use Tailwind with material-ui